# Identifying if a number/string contains a digit 6

Tags: javascript

How can we identify if a number/string contains the digit 6?

Comment: What have you tried? What are approach(es) that you think could work? (A "regular expression" or "index of search" are likely the easiest ..)

Comment: Use `indexOf`. Are you a beginner in programming?

Comment: While strings can contain digits, numbers can't. Does the number sixty contain a digit 6? Well, yes in base 10. No in base 2. Your question reflects a category error -- numbers don't contain digits.

Comment: @nhahtdh ya, i am a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript `indexOf()` function like

```
var str="Your string containing 6 or not";
if(str.indexOf(6)==-1) {
// don't contains
} else {
//contains
}
```

OR with regular expression `.search`

```
 var str="Your string containing 6 or not";
    var pat=/6/
    if(str.search(pat,str)==-1) {
    // don't contains
    } else {
    //contains
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use underscore.js, then it would be:

```
_.contains("myString", "6");
```

Or use `.indexOf()`:

```
"myString".indexOf("6") >= 0
```

Comment: For the love of --- underscore.js does "lots of cool things", but **why** use it for this?

Comment: (All browsers [of any interest] support `String.indexOf` since it was defined in ECMAScript 3rd edition.)

Comment: Because while overkill here, it may be a handy way to get your toes wet with underscore.js.  String.indexOf is probably better.  I never remember that String.indexOf will exist when Array.indexOf doesn't.

Comment: +1 for `.indexOf()`, which [is loads faster](http://jsperf.com/indexof-versus-regex) than regex for a simple case like this. (Though honestly, undersccore.js should take a back seat to it.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`RegExp::test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test):

```
> /6/.test('16')
true
> /6/.test(6001)
true
```

Q.E.D.

Comment: `::` looks weird for JS.